# service mongod start fail with replica set

Tags: mongodb, replicaset

I'm starting my `mongod` with the following command:

```
mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --replSet rs0
```

It works fine and I can configure the replica set. When I try to to launch `mongod` with `service mongod start` command it fails with the following error:

> Starting database mongod                                      [fail]

I have no error in `var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log`, `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/syslog.1`.
I found this work-around solution to run as `mongod` as a service:

`mongod --port 27017 --dbpath /var/lib/mongodb/ --replSet rs0 --fork --logpath /var/log/mongodb/mongodb.log` or `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`

I'm running on mongodb 2.6. `rs.initiate()` worked fine. 
I added `fork = true` and `replSet = rs0` in my `/etc/mongod.conf`.

How can I start MongoDB by using `service mongod start`?

Comment: You should check the errors in the MongoDB log file and post it here when you're using `service mongod start`.

Comment: there is nothing in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log when I do 'service mongod start'

Comment: what type and version of linux are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 for testing before deploy and debian wheezy on my servers.